# Prove that there is no simple group $G$ of order $3^3\cdot7\cdot13\cdot409$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

This is from Dummit and Foote Chapter 6.2 Exercise 29 and there is a hint to work in the permutation representation of degree $819$.

In Exercise 28 we reduced to:
$n_3=2863$
$n_7=47853$
$n_{13}=25767$
$n_{409}=819$

I found a proof here: https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780471433347-abstract-algebra-third-edition/214/exercises/29/

What I don't understand is, why can't we have besides an orbit of $1$ and an orbit of order $409$ a second orbit of order $409$. This would neatly sum up to $819$, the number of Sylow $409$-subgroups.

Comment: Are the comments and links of [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365811/hypothetical-simple-group-of-order-1004913) helpful?

Comment: Yes they do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard: Thanks for your considerations. We have an action of $N_G(P)$ (where $P\in\operatorname{Syl}_{409}(G)$) by conjugation on the Sylow $409$-subgroups, not a left action by $G$, thus it's not transitive and we have therefore more than $1$ orbit.

Comment: @Tretro Forgive me. I thought you were asking about the action of $G$ on $Syl_{409}(G)$ by conjugation. Now I understand that we have a $P\in Syl_{409}(G)$, and we're looking at the action of $N_G(P)$ on $Syl_{409}(G)$ by conjugation.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that NG(P) is not an abelian group (otherwise the normalizer of sylow 3 subgroup would have prime factor 409). Then n3 of NG(P) is 409. 
Suppose Q is another sylow 409 subgroup, denote NG(P)=U, NG(Q)=V, then U intersects with V is a group of order 1 or 3 (it can't be 409 since otherwise they would share the same sylow 409 group). 
That means there exists a sylow 3 subgroup in U\V, acting on Q as an orbit of length 3 by conjugation. That is, U acts on Q by conjugation results in an orbit of length 3*409, overflowing n409.