# "Simple" group of order $1004913$ problem, fixed point part

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $1004913 = 3^3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 409$. We suppose that $G$ is simple. We want to obtain a contradiction.

This is the Exercise 29 in Chapter 6.2 of Dummit-Foote. As far as I know, in MSE, there are two QAs: [QA1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514993/prove-that-there-is-no-simple-group-g-of-order-33-cdot7-cdot13-cdot409?noredirect=1&lq=1), [QA2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365811/hypothetical-simple-group-of-order-1004913?noredirect=1&lq=1). And I found [an exercise](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Etb65536/algebra_materials/winter10.pdf) and [a solution](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-an-algebraist/2009/3065.htm).

I have determined $n_3, n_7, n_{13}, n_{409}$ uniquely as mentioned in QAs above. We consider the action of $G$ on $Syl_{409}(G)$ by conjugation. Let $G \to S_{819}$ be the permutation representation of this. I see that elements of order $3$ in $N_G(P)$ fix exactly $3$ points in $S_{819}$, where $P \in Syl_{409}(G)$. However, I don’t know how to obtain a contradiction by this.

According to QAs above, elements of order $3$ in $G$ fix exactly $9$ points in $S_{819}$, which follows from Burnside’s lemma or some higher theory. In Dummit-Foote, Burnside’s lemma is stated in the last chapter about character theory. Therefore, I wonder if there is a solution without it, i.e., solution with tools in Chapters 1-6.

P.S. This question does not mean that I hesitate to learn theorems beyond Dummit-Foote Chapters 1-6. I have found that Burnside’s lemma appears in an early chapter in Rotman. I am going to try to learn it later. However, I want to know or guess what the solution that the authors expected is.

---

**Update**: After I thought twice again, I solved this exercise as follows. We can show that $P \cap Q = 1$ for any $P, Q \in Syl_{3}(G)$ with $P \neq Q$. By counting elements of $G$, it follows that there is no chance of existence of an element of order other than $1, 3, 3^2, 3^3, 7, 13, 409$. In particular, the number of elements of either order $3$, $3^2$ or $3^3$ is determined as $N = 7 \cdot 409 \cdot 26$. We count the number $M$ of elements of order $3$ in $\bigcup_{P \in Syl_{409}(G)} N_G(P)$. Noting that there are no element of order $3 \cdot 409$, we see that $N_G(P)$ is not cyclic, i.e., each $N_G(P)$ has $409$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. By the fact that elements of order $3$ in $N_G(P)$ fix exactly $3$ points in $S_{819}$, we see that $M = 2 \cdot 409 \cdot 819 / 3$, which gives a contradiction since $M > N$.

Although I solved the exercise, I have not understand other solutions. I will be appreciated if you could tell me answers of the following questions.

1. How can we prove that $P$ is elementary Abelian for $P \in Syl_{3}(G)$? I know that it suffices to prove that there is no element of order $9$ or that $P$ is Abelian. For the latter, the N/C theorem tells me that $P$ is elementary Abelian.
2. How can we prove that any elements of order $3$ within $P$ fix the same number of points in $S_{819}$? If we can show this, I know that it follows that all the elements of order $3$ in $G$ fix the same number of points in $S_{819}$ since Sylow groups are conjugate.

If I can show item 1., I know how I can use Derek’s hint. If I can show item 2., now I know how I can apply Burnside’s lemma to gain a contradiction.

---

**Update 2**: I saw Derek’s second advice and I decided to determine all the five groups of order $p^3$ for odd primes $p$. When I wrote item 1., I knew the isomorphism types of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ for the three Abelian groups $G$ of order $p^3$. Now I know $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ for the two non-Abelian groups, too. Hence, I have managed to prove that $P$ is elementary Abelian for $P \in Syl_{3}(G)$ and to obtain contradiction following Derek's first advice. I would like to thank Derek here.

Actually, I have not seen how to prove item 2. yet. But it's time to move on to the next study.

Comment: It is crucial to know what is allowed to use. If the deep result , that every finite group with odd order is solvable , is allowed , the claim is trivial.

Comment: According to QA2, a Sylow 3-subgroup is abelian. That together with an element of order 3 fixing 3 points in $S_{819}$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: As a side note: I have not verified the original paper, but according to Dummit-Foote (p.212), the nonexistence of a simple group of order $1004913$ is among the cases to be dealt with in the original proof of Feit–Thompson’s theorem.

Comment: If you accept the values of $n_p$ then the normalizer of a  Sylow $13$-subgroup $P$ has order $27 \times 13$ and since a Sylow $13$-subgroup does not have normalizer divisible by $27$, $P$ must have an automorphism of order $13$. The only group of order $27$ with such an automorphism is $Z_3^3$.

Comment: @KazuneTakahashi I highly doubted that Feit-Thompson had to look at individual group orders, especially when it is an elementary exercise. As a matter of fact, the number 1004913 does not occur in the original paper.

Comment: I asked a question about the description of D-F in MO. https://mathoverflow.net/q/455480/176161

Comment: Derek's outline is wonderful, but I wanted to remark you don't need to classify the groups of order 27. If $P$ is a group of that order, then first you can show an automorphism of order 13 can only fix the identity. Then show that $Z(P)\neq1$ must be the whole group, so $P$ is Abelian. Finally show that $\{x^3: x\in P\}$ must be the trivial subgroup, so $P$ is elementary Abelian.

Comment: For part (2), you can show: if $x$ and $y$ are permutations of prime order, and $x$ normalizes, but doesn't centralize, $\langle y\rangle$, then $x$ can fix at most one point of each cycle of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left|G\right|=1004913=3^{3}7\cdot 13\cdot 409$ and suppose $G$ is simple. Then the Sylow $3$-subgroup is elementary abelian and the class equation implies there are at most $2$ cycle types for elements of order $3$. On the other hand, using the permutation representation in $S_{819}$, the normalizers for the Sylow $7$, $13$, and $409$ subgroups produce $3$ distinct cycle types for elements of order $3$, a contradiction. It must be that $G$ is not simple. Thus the result.